# VSTO write to a cell in Excel!

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Why does this work:

```
((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet).get_Range("A1", "A1").Value2 = text;
```

But this doesn't:

```
Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
activeSheet.Cells[0, 0] = text;
```

I need to do it the second way as I need to loop with rowIndex and colIndex. How can I do that?

I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional
>   information: Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800A03EC

Answer (score 14):

The only thing you're missing (other than using 1 based indexes) is to cast the cell reference to a range explicitly:

```
Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
int endRow = 5;
int endCol = 6;

for(int idxRow = 1; idxRow <= endRow; idxRow++)
{
    for(int idxCol = 1; idxCol <= endCol; idxCol)
    {
        ((Excel.Range)activeSheet.Cells[idxRow, idxCol]).Value2 = "Kilroy wuz here";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I just wanted to make people who read this know the faster way to populate a large amount of cell values is using a object[,] eg:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3847094/495455

Comment: With c# 4 and the 'dynamic' keyword one can now just: dynamic cell = sheet.Cells[1, 1]; cell.Value2 = "hi there";  More - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx