# Fastest way to access live Excel data/properties from another process with .NET

Tags: .net, excel, automation, com-interop

[Fastest way to interface between live (unsaved) Excel data and C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840270/fastest-way-to-interface-between-live-unsaved-excel-data-and-c-sharp-objects) features a very knowledgeable discussion about how to access Excel data efficiently. According to the answers two recommendations are to use Excel-Dna or Add-in Express.

I believe Excel-Dna and Add-in Express both require to run as an Excel add-in. In my case the business logic runs in another process and creates an Excel instance (`New Excel.Application()`). On changes in Excel it needs to update internal objects.

Getting the cell values from Excel can efficiently be done with `DirectCast(Range.Value, Object(,))`. Unfortunately, this is not possible for other properties like `Range.Text` or `Range.NumberFormat`. As expected, iterating the through cells is very slow.

What do you think is the most efficient way to access the Excel data from the main process? One idea I came up with is to add an add-in to Excel (using say Excel-Dna) which aggregates the data and then posts it to the main application. As I do not have much experience with cross-AppDomain marshalling I would appreciate an assessment if this is a viable approach or another one should be preferred.

Comment: Its usually not a good idea to get Range.Text values because you can lose precision or get ### instead of a number if the column width is too small. See http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/ for a comprison of .Text .Value and .Value2

Comment: Agreed, it's better to use .Value(2) and .NumberFormat. So the question remains how to efficiently query .NumberFormat (plus additional formatting properties I'd like to evaluate in a second step).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can read the file using one of the direct file readers, instead of going through Excel. (If need be you can automate Excel to save the file, or a copy of part of the file.)

As a start I suggest you look at [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), but there are many similar projects. ClosedXML look like an active project and tries to mirror the COM interface. [I have no experience with it myself.]

Comment: Hi Govert, Thanks for your input. If you are saying so I am now 100% sure that Excel-Dna was not made for this task :). Using XML data is an interesting workaround, I will look into this approach. The XML data is only accessible if saving as XML file or via the clipboard, right?

Comment: The xml files are the default file format since Excel 2007 - all the .xlsx files are just zip files with all the content in xml. So it is the normal Excel 2007/2010 files that are processed by ClosedXML. I don't think it would work through the Clipboard though.
If you do it the other way - have some add-in running inside Excel and make your own cross-process data transfer, Excel-DNA would be the ideal tool for the add-in, since you can read the data quickly with the C API.

Comment: Actually, I was planning to use the [Excel 2003 XML Spreadsheet format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx) since I hope it involves less overhead when writing and reading. The data can also be retrieved from the clipboard (format "XML Spreadsheet") but I know it violates UI principles to highjack the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the number format from a range of cells one-by-one is going to be slow with any technology (and slower with Interop) and there is no way that I know of to get a corresponding array of different number formats with a single object model call.
If your excel data is in clusters of formats you may be able to exploit the fact that `Range("C1:C4").Numberformat` will get a single number format if all the cells in the range have the same number format but if any of the number formats within the range differ you will get a Null

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. As I think there is no way to determine a range that has a common format it won't be possible to use NumberFormat on a range (and get Null if it's not consistent) because I have no information about the formats.

Comment: OK: Curiosity question - why do you need formatted data anyway- its not the real data and loses precision etc compared to the real values?

Comment: It's for displaying purposes: I would like the user to be able to set a switch like "Formats as in Excel" so he/she does not need to worry about number formats twice. The real data from .Value/Value2 will be stored and used in conjunction with the format to generate the output.