# Error 0x800A03EC when creating an excel data sheet

Tags: c#, datagridview

Iam trying to  create an excel file with the info within the datagridview which I get from a db. but I get the following error  Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)... the error seems to be in the line with **

the code is within a button click

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel1 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { };

        Workbook work1 = excel1.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws1 = (Worksheet)excel1.ActiveSheet;

        excel1.Visible = true;

        ws1.Cells[1,1] = "ID";
        ws1.Cells[1,2]= "NAME";


       ** ws1.Cells[1,1]= dataGridView1[1,1];
        ws1.Cells[1, 2] = dataGridView1[1,2];
```

Comment: Have you debugged? Did you google the error?

Answer (score 0):

There are references available, for example see:

- COM exception diagnosing:

  > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/af1y26ew(v=vs.80).aspx
- Depending upon what operating system you are using, an old excel file access bug:

  > https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d6c383a-94eb-4898-9d22-aa4bb69be25b/excel-interop-systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x800a03ec-microsoft-office-excel?forum=vbgeneral
- > > "*When working with excel, it is better to work with the ranges instead than directly with the cells. The reason is that with the cells you are using late binding and you only see the COM errors":*
  >
  > https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a9ba772-f3d8-413e-8243-2846dfdb8b22/probem-with-systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x800a03ec-exception-from-hresult?forum=vbgeneral
- When setting cells does not work:

  > [VSTO write to a cell in Excel!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856196/vsto-write-to-a-cell-in-excel)
- And lastly...

  > [Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714626/exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec-error)

These are but a few to look at.